# how to generate dates between two ranges in apache spark or spark sql?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark

I am trying to create date values using pyspark / spark sql for the period 0001-1-1 to 9999/12/31.
I have python script to produce dates for the above range, but when i tried to create a spark df i am unable to do that. Can anyone help me ?

```py
pd.period_range(start='0001-01-01', end='9999-12-31')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you would use the dates for. You can though generate using array_zip, sequence and day interval.

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,'0001-01-01','9999-12-31')], ('id','start','end'))
df.withColumn('start',to_date('start')).withColumn('end',to_date('end')).selectExpr('id',"inline(arrays_zip(sequence(start,end,interval 1 day)))")
```

Comment: hi @wwnde i just get one row which has both  start date and end date. I need to generate the entire dates for 10000 years between 0001-1-1 and 9999-12-31. is it possible ?